# Why does my nav bar affect the centering of my image?

Tags: html, css

If I have no nav bar, then my image is centred fine.

If I then add my nav bar (using an unordered list horizontal list) then my image is aligned more to the left of the page.

It's just a basic layout

```
<div>
<img ...>
<ul>....</ul>
</div>
```

Here is the full code (it isn't much, but it's still too much to post on here)
https://jsfiddle.net/ps84wbx0/

Unfortunately I can't add the image but I'm sure the case is the same for any image.

This is the page I am trying to create

[image]

Here's a snippet:

```css
/* Logo Styling */
div.homepage {
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
}

img.homepage {
    position: relative;
    left: -50%;
}


/*Nav Bar Styling*/
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-left: -50%;
}

li.button {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
    padding: 0 4em;
    font: 300 1.5em/3em 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: .08em;
    color: #fff;
    background: #0090C0;
    border-radius: 2px; 
}

li.button:hover{
    background: #007DA7;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(black, .5) inset;
}
 
a:link, a:hover, a:active, a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="homepage">
    <img src="images/homepage.png" class="homepage">
    <ul>
        <li class="button"><a href="index.html" data-text="Home">Home</a></li>
        <li class="button"><a href="about.html" data-text="About">About</a></li>
        <li class="button"><a href="services.html" data-text="Services">Services</a></li>
        <li class="button"><a href="contact.html" data-text="Contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: my screen is 2560x1440 if that makes a difference. It seems to be an issue when its full screen, but when its not full screen, it just looks like its the nav bar which isn't centered correctly

Comment: Check if this helps - https://jsfiddle.net/ps84wbx0/1/

Comment: @DmitriyDemir Yes that aligned the nav bar and the image correctly, but it now aligned both of them completely to the left. should i put a container around both and then centre the container?

Comment: Oops, didn't check on a bigger screen. Here: https://jsfiddle.net/ps84wbx0/2/ I'm gonna post is as an answer in a minute.

Comment: works perfectly. cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to solve this, but I think this one is one of the simplest. I've only changed the CSS of `div.homepage`, `img.homepage` and `ul`. Here's the code:

```css
/* Logo Styling */
div.homepage {
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

img.homepage {
    position: relative;
}


/*Nav Bar Styling*/
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

li.button {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
    padding: 0 4em;
    font: 300 1.5em/3em 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: .08em;
    color: #fff;
    background: #0090C0;
    border-radius: 2px; 
}

li.button:hover{
    background: #007DA7;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(black, .5) inset;
}
 
a:link, a:hover, a:active, a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="homepage">
    <img src="images/homepage.png" class="homepage">
    <ul>
        <li class="button"><a href="index.html" data-text="Home">Home</a></li>
        <li class="button"><a href="about.html" data-text="About">About</a></li>
        <li class="button"><a href="services.html" data-text="Services">Services</a></li>
        <li class="button"><a href="contact.html" data-text="Contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```